# Exception: PlatformException(channel-error, Unable to establish connection on channel., null, null)

Tags: flutter, dart, runtime, flutter-dependencies, dart-pub

Suddenly this error appears in the debug console. I do not know what I did wrong.

I was Using flutter version 3.3.3

For Me Changing below plugins in pubspec.yml helps me

`firebase_analytics: ^9.1.9`

`firebase_auth: ^3.6.2`

`firebase_core: ^1.20.0`

`firebase_dynamic_links: ^4.3.3`

`firebase_messaging: ^12.0.1`

`firebase_storage: ^10.3.4`

`app_settings: ^4.2.0`

`share_plus: 4.0.10`

after that just

```
flutter clean
```

```
flutter pub get
```

and now enjoy !!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.